# Loading richtextbox content from xml

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a RichTextBox where the user can format the text and save as an xml document. I save the RichtextBox.Rtf content in my xml document.
When i try to load the saved data from xml. The RichTextBox doesn't format the text based on the Rtf content from XML.

Sample Code used for creating XML

```
XmlTextWriter objXmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(path, null);
objXmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
objXmlTextWriter.WriteStartDocument();    
objXmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("MyData");

RichTextBox tBox = (RichTextBox)sender;
objXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("RcText");
objXmlWriter.WriteString(tBox.Rtf);
objXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

objXmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
objXmlWriter.Flush();
objXmlWriter.Close();
```

Sample Code used for reloading the RichTextBox from XML

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(selPath);
XmlNodeList oDescendant = doc.SelectNodes("/MyData");
foreach (XmlNode xn in oDescendant)
{
    ID++;

    RichTextBox rcTxt = new RichTextBox();
    rcTxt.Name = "rtd" + ID;

    rcTxt.Rtf = xn["RcText"].InnerText;
}
```

Sample content as seen after loading the content to richtext from XML.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 Sample \b Text\b0\par
}
```

I am not sure where I am wrong. Please give your suggestions.

I tried searching for some similar cases but was not helpful.
Some of the links which i referred : [Code Project Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12932/Saving-and-Restoring-RichTextBox-Formatted-Text-Al)

Comment: Where are you loading the rich text controls onto a form?  The code looks decent to load the data properly.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Yes. I create the control dynamically and add the same to the holder placed in the mdi child form.

Comment: @JohnKoerner I even tried the SaveFile and LoadFile options but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: If I manually add a richtextbox to a form and then set richTextBox1.Rtf to the string in this post, it renders properly.  Look at your XML.  It is escaping the rich text and adding extra "\" in there?

Comment: @JohnKoerner Thank You for your reply John. Adding @ solved the problem.

Comment: Hi dude, can you give me a hint how you did this richtextbox to save its content (from the user) to an XML ? I really need this and so far I can not get it going in the right direction... Any help and links would be much appreciated :)

Comment: @Pepys You need to create the xml and save the data from the available RichText control. The above sample will guide you to create the XML and save the content. If you need only the data you can use ctrl.Text. If you need to save it as Rtf file you can make use of the ctrl.SaveFile method.

Comment: Yeah okay but in this first method you posted here , where do you save the actual xml file? In a hardcoded path of the pc?

Comment: @Pepys After the editing. I have a button to save. I get the path from the user using the savefiledialog and save it in the required location.