# RichTextBox fails to format the Rtf content

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading richtextbox content from xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957631/loading-richtextbox-content-from-xml)

I am trying to save and load the RichTextBox content from a XML file. I save the Rtf format content in my XML to include all the formatting with the data. When i try to reload the content from XML file, the RichTextBox doesn't format the content instead it displays all the Rtf formatting code in UI.

Sample content which i try to save : Sample **Text**

Content displayed in RichTextBox control below:

```
{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1033{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\f0\\fs17 Sample \\b Text\\b0\\par\r\n}\r\n
```

Is there any solution for this? Or suggest me some alternatives to include RichContent.

You can find more information regarding this problem from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957631/loading-richtextbox-content-from-xml)

Thanks In Advance,
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string rtfString = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\deff0\\deflang1033{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fnil\\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}\r\n\\viewkind4\\uc1\\pard\\f0\\fs17 Sample \\b Text\\b0\\par\r\n}\r\n";
richTextBox1.Rtf = rtfString;
```

// EDIT:
You can load this string from rtf file, but it will be long and not effective:

```
richTextBox1.LoadFile(@"F:\SimpleText.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
```

But, I really don't get it why doesn't my first code work for you. Because it works fine for me:
[image]

I suggest You're doing something wrong. Can You ,maybe, attach your solution some how if it's simple.

Comment: You shouldn't put `@` in front of that string.

Comment: @Dmytro Tsiniavsky Thanks for the immediate reply but unfortunately it didn't solve the issue. I still get the same content in RichTextBox.

Comment: Yes, of course, thanks. It will parse \\ as \;

Comment: Yes now it displays like it this way "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 Sample \b Text\b0\par
}"

Comment: Do we have any other alternatives for handling the richtext content ?